# android, unity, onesignal -- where to place the sound file?

Tags: android, audio, unity-game-engine, onesignal

Saying that I'm new to android development would be an understatement. I'm trying to figure out where to place a sound file in my unity directory such that onesignal, a third party notification server, can access it for this a particular api method:

android_sound:  StringOptional
Sound file that is included in your app to play instead of the default device notification sound.
NOTE: Leave off file extension for Android.
Example: "notification"

reference: https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification

I get a build error when I place it in res/raw, and anywhere else in the google play services library[image]

Where does it go?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to place the `OneSignalNotificationRes` folder from our [Unity Example Project](https://github.com/one-signal/OneSignal-Unity-SDK/tree/master/UnityOneSignalExample/Assets/Plugins/Android/OneSignalNotificationRes) into your `Assets/Plugins/Android/` folder. Replace the example icons and sound files with your own.

More details found on the bottom of the [3. Android](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup) section in our Unity setup guide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

İn Android,

Just move your .mp3 file to

res/raw   folder

So your .mp3 file should be shown as src/raw/onesignal_default_sound.mp3

Then build your code and send push.

Also you can user another file names but you have to add Sound File Name while sending push[image]

Enjoy it ^^